# Degree symbol breaks URL detector

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, url-encoding

[This was originally posted on Travel Meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/degree-symbol-breaks-uri-detector). I am reposting here to add visibility to the issue.

---

The URI detector breaks when it encounters a degree symbol (°) or U+00B9:

https://www.google.com.pe/maps/place/3°08'06.5%22S+59°54'08.7%22W/@-3.1351316,-59.9374329,14z

The link was copied and pasted from the browser's address field. This problem is exacerbated on travel since we often link to Google maps.